# Как выбирать первый элемент массива Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular2

Всем привет! Подскажите как сделать выборку первого элемента массива programms ?? Ps: сейчас все элементы programms выводится!

Заранее всем спасибо!!

.json

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "name":"Еда",
   "about":"описание телеканала",
   "img":"Картинка",
   "programms":[  
      {  
         "name":"Утренные салаты",
         "start":"07-00",
         "finish":"09-00"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Новые Ритцепты",
         "start":"09-00",
         "finish":"10-00"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Новые блюдо с Настией",
         "start":"10-10",
         "finish":"12-00"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Ритцепты Дня",
         "start":"12-10",
         "finish":"13-00"
      }
   ]
}
```

page.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let channel of channel.programms">    
        <ion-icon name="play" item-left large></ion-icon>
        <h2>{{channel.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{channel.start}} - {{channel.finish}}</p>
      </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let channel of channel.programms; let f = first">
    <ion-icon name="play" item-left large></ion-icon>
    <h2>{{channel.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{channel.start}} - {{channel.finish}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="f">I'm the first one!!!</p>
</ion-item>
```

> вы щас шутите ??? вопрос внимательно читайте!!!! Я только первый элемент хочу вывести!

А в чём тогда вообще проблема???

```
<ion-item *ngIf="channel.programms[0]">
    <ion-icon name="play" item-left large></ion-icon>
    <h2>{{channel.programms[0].name}}</h2>
    <p>{{channel.programms[0].start}} - {{channel.programms[0].finish}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: вы щас шутите ??? вопрос внимательно читайте!!!! Я только первый элемент хочу вывести!

Comment: {  
         "name":"Утренные салаты",
         "start":"07-00",
         "finish":"09-00"
      }

Comment: Только первый элемент вывести, теперь поняли ??

Comment: @AccessDenied, а я что, только десятый вывожу???????????

Comment: Спасибо код работает, но исправил надо без "[0]" *ngIf="channel.programms"

Спасибо огромное !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFirstProgram(){
   return channel.programms ? channel.programms[0]:null;
}

<ion-item *ngIf="getFirstProgram()">    
        <ion-icon name="play" item-left large></ion-icon>
        <h2>{{getFirstProgram().name}}</h2>
        <p>{{getFirstProgram().start}} - {{getFirstProgram().finish}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: тут данные которые с Api приходит, не получится загонять в функцию!!